# Is there a single word to describe a combination of a projected video and a live stage performance?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

We're developing an entertainment module for a conclave. The format agreed upon is this: an audiovisual is projected on the screen, but is punctuated by live performances on the stage. For example, a sequence of a guy driving to work in rush hour is punctuated by a dimming of lights and while the AV fades out, real actors are seen driving on stage, seated in cutouts of cars, while the music changes tempo. The lights dim again and we see footage of the guy entering his office lobby- a 'tableau' of sorts, for want of a better/appropriate word.

My question is, is there a word that describes this type of live-and-screened piece? I googled, and found the Japanese word *Rensageki*  and *New School Cinema.* I don't know about the Japanese word, but *New School Cinema* is far too generic/bland for me.

Is there a single word to describe this better than "Tableau", which is what I've temporarily titled the script? Ideally, I'm looking for a single word. If none exists, a short and descriptive phrase, or a combo word like 'docudrama' will also do - as long as it is succinct/definitive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would call such a performance *[**multimedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia)*.

Comment: Thanks-I'll wait a while to see if any other suggestions/recommendations come by.

Comment: +1 Here's an [example](http://www.guardian.co.uk/stage/theatreblog/2006/dec/04/wavessetsahighwatermarkfo) that uses "multimedia" and "multimedia theatre" to describe a performance where "performance where theatre and video come together".

Comment: @ Hugo. Thanks for the link. The diatribe articulates many of my own feelings about such a combination!

Answer (score 1):

What you describe sounds like an evolution of the *sound and light show* with the inclusion of live actors. (The term is a translation of the French *son et lumière*, because the concept of large-scale video projection accompanied by music was originally French -- for more, see [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_et_lumi%C3%A8re_(show)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_et_lumi%C3%A8re_%28show%29) ).

'Multimedia' is not inaccurate, but it is a very general term that covers many other concepts.

Answer (score 0):

How about ***[simulcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulcast)***?  Edit:  Just realized I'm very late to the game...

Wikipedia:

> Simulcast, a portmanteau of simultaneous broadcast, is the broadcasting of programs or events across more than one medium, or more than one service on the same medium, at exactly the same time.

Answer (score -1):

It's a subset of *performance art*.